# Wifite-master error in 'module' has no attrib 'getuid' - Python

Tags: python, security, wifi

I would like to ask how can I fix wifite error

Here's the error

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Privilege Escalation\Password Attacks\Offline Attacks\Wifite\wifite-m
aster\wifite.py", line 3360, in <module>
    engine.Start()
  File "C:\Privilege Escalation\Password Attacks\Offline Attacks\Wifite\wifite-m
aster\wifite.py", line 1354, in Start
    self.RUN_CONFIG.ConfirmRunningAsRoot()
  File "C:\Privilege Escalation\Password Attacks\Offline Attacks\Wifite\wifite-m
aster\wifite.py", line 252, in ConfirmRunningAsRoot
    if os.getuid() != 0:
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getuid'
```

can't put the code.. it's too long..
download wifite if you want to see the code..

anyone knows how to fix this?

I've got Python 3.4.3 (latest as of now) so IDK if it has to do with the version.. tried it with the older version.. didn't work also.. python programmers told me nothing was wrong and told me to update python which I did but still the same problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running Windows. The project web page says:

> Designed and tested on Linux; works with Backtrack 5, BlackBuntu,
>   BackBox, and Pentoo! Linux only; **no windows or OSX support** (but you're
>   welcome to try).

The [`os.getuid`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.getuid) function is only available on Unix, that's why you're getting an error.

It's not necessary to change your OS, just use a Virtual Machine with some Linux distro!

Comment: oh okay.,. but.. a lot got it running on windows..

Comment: is there a way or alternative that works exactly the same.. but for windows
I tried running it also in cygwin didn't work.. haven't tried - and will never since my laptop only has 1GB RAM (upgraded) - using VM

Comment: @AndrewAngeloBarrientos I don't know how many unix-specific functions this package uses, but maybe you can try porting it to windows by yourself. There are also lightweight linux distros such as Lubuntu ([http://lubuntu.net/), you can try install it along with Windows, or use an old version of VMWare!